# Logcat errors when running android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm running an emulator targeting 2.3 (API Level 9). I've removed all downloaded apps (which includes any code that I've written) but I still get all of these logcat errors when I start up the emulator:

```
[ollie@devdataload scripts]$ startlogcat.sh 
- waiting for device -
E/Zygote  (   32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
E/Zygote  (   32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
E/BatteryService(   61): usbOnlinePath not found
E/BatteryService(   61): batteryVoltagePath not found
E/BatteryService(   61): batteryTemperaturePath not found
E/SurfaceFlinger(   61): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
E/SensorService(   61): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)
E/System  (   61): Failure starting core service
E/System  (   61): java.lang.SecurityException
E/System  (   61):      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
E/System  (   61):      at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
E/System  (   61):      at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
E/System  (   61):      at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:206)
E/EventHub(   61): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
E/EventHub(   61): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
E/SoundPool(   61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
E/SoundPool(   61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
E/SoundPool(   61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
E/SoundPool(   61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
E/SoundPool(   61): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
E/UsbObserver(   61): 
E/UsbObserver(   61): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/UsbObserver(   61):   at com.android.server.UsbObserver.init(UsbObserver.java:131)
E/UsbObserver(   61):   at com.android.server.UsbObserver.<init>(UsbObserver.java:65)
E/UsbObserver(   61):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:402)
E/ThrottleService(   61): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
E/logwrapper(  125): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
E/logwrapper(  126): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
E/logwrapper(  127): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
```

I'd like to try to clean these up so that I can know for sure that any errors I'm looking at are being caused by my code. Does anyone else get these error messages and do you fix them or just ignore them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common logging practice in Android is smth like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static final String TAG=MyClass.class.getName();

    // some stuff

    Log.i(TAG, "My log message");
}
```

So when you're inspecting LogCat messages you can filter your logs using those `TAG`. This is way to ignore other logs.

Answer (score 3):

If they don't deal with your application, you can ignore them.  There is nothing you can do as a developer to fix a manufacturer problem on other peoples phones or even yours for that matter (well short of a custom rom).

Edit: I'd also add that some errors/warnings are normal and are not to be of concern.

Comment: OP said this was an emulator, not a device from a manufacturer. It is a bit odd that the emulators from Google don't start cleanly, but I've noticed the same thing.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I agree with you @TedHopp I am looking at my logcat and was going to ask the question as to why these errors occur. Whats confusing is that they occur on things that the emulator clearly does not have due to its obvious constraints.

Comment: First they stopped google api support on all the good emulators in the market more than a year back and then they are lazy enough not to fix their own emulator. This is like forced usage