# Error message during running a simple project

Tags: android, logcat, android-virtual-device

I have a simple project with only one button in it,but when running,these errors occur.If it is the eclipse has wrong, it is impossible because I have downloaded the eclipse from official site. who can help me?

```
07-29 03:53:06.418: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
07-29 03:53:24.189: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
07-29 03:53:27.469: E/BatteryService(76): usbOnlinePath not found
07-29 03:53:27.469: E/BatteryService(76): batteryVoltagePath not found
07-29 03:53:27.477: E/BatteryService(76): batteryTemperaturePath not found
07-29 03:53:27.508: E/SurfaceFlinger(76): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
07-29 03:53:27.818: E/SensorService(76): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)
07-29 03:54:11.447: E/System(76): Failure starting core service
07-29 03:54:11.447: E/System(76): java.lang.SecurityException
07-29 03:54:11.447: E/System(76):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-29 03:54:11.447: E/System(76):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
07-29 03:54:11.447: E/System(76):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
07-29 03:54:11.447: E/System(76):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:206)
07-29 03:54:11.508: E/EventHub(76): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
07-29 03:54:11.508: E/EventHub(76): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
07-29 03:54:12.939: E/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-29 03:54:12.939: E/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-29 03:54:12.958: E/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-29 03:54:12.968: E/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-29 03:54:12.968: E/SoundPool(76): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-29 03:54:13.018: E/UsbObserver(76): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 03:54:13.018: E/UsbObserver(76):  at com.android.server.UsbObserver.init(UsbObserver.java:131)
07-29 03:54:13.018: E/UsbObserver(76):  at com.android.server.UsbObserver.<init>(UsbObserver.java:65)
07-29 03:54:13.018: E/UsbObserver(76):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:402)
07-29 03:54:21.917: E/ThrottleService(76): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
07-29 03:54:21.947: E/ThrottleService(76): Error reading data file
07-29 03:54:22.677: E/logwrapper(178): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-29 03:54:22.868: E/logwrapper(181): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-29 03:54:23.037: E/logwrapper(185): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-29 03:54:25.037: E/logwrapper(210): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-29 03:54:25.387: E/logwrapper(214): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-29 03:54:25.468: E/logwrapper(217): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76): Start proc android.process.media for broadcast com.android.providers.downloads/.DownloadReceiver: pid=294 uid=10000 gids={1006, 1015, 2001, 3003}Load: 4.88 / 1.54 / 0.55
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76): CPU usage from 0ms to 9380ms later:
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   39% 76/system_server: 24% user + 15% kernel / faults: 747 minor
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   15% 239/com.android.launcher: 11% user + 4.2% kernel / faults: 936 minor
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   14% 258/zygote: 11% user + 2.3% kernel / faults: 409 minor
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   6.3% 167/com.android.phone: 4.9% user + 1.3% kernel / faults: 190 minor
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   6.2% 88/bootanimation: 4.8% user + 1.3% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   2.3% 274/com.android.deskclock: 1.2% user + 1% kernel / faults: 197 minor
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   1.9% 40/adbd: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   1.8% 170/com.android.systemui: 0.9% user + 0.8% kernel / faults: 53 minor

07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   19% 76/system_server: 13% user + 5.8% kernel / faults: 19 minor
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):     14% 89/ActivityManager: 10% user + 3.8% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):     5.8% 84/SurfaceFlinger: 2.9% user + 2.9% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):     0.9% 81/Compiler: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):     0.9% 83/Binder Thread #: 0.9% user + 0% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):     0.9% 218/Binder Thread #: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   8.3% 88/bootanimation: 7.2% user + 1% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):     7.2% 92/BootAnimation: 6.2% user + 1% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   1.9% 40/adbd: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):   0.3% 170/com.android.systemui: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 1 minor
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76):     0.3% 170/ndroid.systemui: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
07-29 03:55:14.578: E/ActivityManager(76): 100% TOTAL: 63% user + 35% kernel + 0.9% softirq
07-29 03:55:52.089: E/ThrottleService(76): Error reading data file
07-29 03:56:07.668: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(33): failed to extract an album art
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running android emulator?

Please see this: [Logcat errors when running android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965339/logcat-errors-when-running-android-emulator)  to filter your logs