# Error clicking Google+ sign in button in Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I am trying to signin to to my app using Google+ play services.The code doesn't have any errors and it launches in the emulator.But when i click the "signin with google" button i get this error in the logcat

[image]

I am not sure why this happens.Here is my `MainActivity` class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.*;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusClient;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener,
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;
private Button signInButton;
private ProgressDialog mConnectionProgressDialog;
private static PlusClient mPlusClient;
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/  BuyActivity")
    .setScopes("PLUS_LOGIN")  // Space separated list of scopes
    .build();
    // Progress bar to be displayed if the connection failure is not resolved.
    mConnectionProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mConnectionProgressDialog.setMessage("Signing in...");

    signInButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}
public static PlusClient getPlusClientObject() {
    return mPlusClient;
}

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mPlusClient.connect();
}
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mPlusClient.disconnect();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    //signInButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    //signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
     if (mConnectionProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            // The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
            // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
            // connection dialog.
            if (result.hasResolution()) {
              try {
                       result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
               } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                       mPlusClient.connect();
               }
            }
          }
          // Save the result and resolve the connection failure upon a user click.
          mConnectionResult = result;

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mConnectionResult = null;
        mPlusClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) { //this is called when the user has successfully signed in
     String accountName = mPlusClient.getAccountName();
        Toast.makeText(this, accountName + " is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent logoutIntention = new Intent(this, LogoutActivity.class);
        startActivity(logoutIntention);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
     Log.d(TAG, "disconnected");

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button && !mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
        if (mConnectionResult == null) {
            mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
        } else {
            try {
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                // Try connecting again.
                mConnectionResult = null;
                mPlusClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

and my app references `google-play-services_lib` which has this structure:

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening.Can anyone help?

Here is the definition of my emulator:

[image]

Comment: it should be a system sound effect. are you running on device? which Android OS version?

Comment: am running on an emulator.I just edited the question to show this.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965339/logcat-errors-when-running-android-emulator ; seems Emulator does not have these files. Please double check on real device.