# Connecting android with MYSQL & PHP localhost

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new in android and i want to connect my app with mysql using php but it doesnt work, is some thing wrong in my code? please help me:

```
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8888/jobs/mobile/home/searchJobs");

        try {

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            //add data for post
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("keywords","keyword for search" ));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", "Location value"));
            //set url encoded entity
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                Toast.makeText(Search_result.this, "response: "+responseStr, 1000).show();

                // you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response

                Log.v("tag", "Response: " +  responseStr);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
```

And this the errors:
[image]

Comment: "but it doesnt work" what happen while your connecting?

Comment: Nothing just some errors occurred in logCat

Comment: Are you using the code inside AsyncTask ? Check your server is working perfect and post some more code

Comment: The server is working no problem with server

Comment: Where are you testing the code on a real android device or on an emulator ?

Comment: What the error says coz iam not able to see the logcat errors properly the image is not proper . Can you describe what the error says ?

Comment: I changed the screen shot can u see that now?

Comment: I think these errors are not the actual problem, Is there any other error or warning is showing with your app name ?

Comment: No there is no more error

Answer (score 0):

Based on your log check the following:

- Check the SDK version in manifest - compile version/targeting latest SDK
- Check emulator settings i've seen the problem output like yours here:
  [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965339/logcat-errors-when-running-android-emulator)